# MySQL - get data from custom field with read-only access to db

Tags: mysql

I have a text field with data, something like:

```
[{"id":10001,"timeStarted":1355729600733,"projectId":10002,"issueId":"29732,","userName":"tester","assignee":"test","status":"STARTED","shared":True,"name":"Session 4","projectName":"IDS","assigneeDisplayName":"First1 Last1"},
 {"id":10002,"timeStarted":1358354188010,"projectId":10002,"issueId":"","userName":"tester","assignee":"test","status":"CREATED","shared":True,"name":"asdf98798","projectName":"IDS","assigneeDisplayName":"First Last"}]
```

but with much more rows, it may be 30-40, and may be 2 more different statuses (total 4).

Is it possible to extract some data from here having read-only access to DB and only using MySQL query?

For example to count number of items with status "Stated" and with status "created".
Additional conditions may apply, e.g. where id is in definite interval.

Comment: Are you asking how you can extract some data from a given JSON response or are you asking how you need to tweak a query that outputs this data? If it is the latter then the output you supplied is irrelevant to your question. You need to share your db query (that outputs this response) instead.

Comment: no, the first, i don't have any query, only know location of this field with JSON in db.

Comment: And what is the language you will be using to do this task? Javascript, PHP or something else?

Comment: If this JSON represents a bunch of different rows in a MySQL table (for example with ids 10001, 10002, and so forth) you can write a query.  If you want help with that you'll need to show us your table schema.  If what you're showing us is the contents of one text field in a MySQL database ... a text field that happens to contain a bunch of JSON-encoded records ... the answer is, no you can't write a MySQL query to summarize the data. You'll need to use PHP or JavaScript or some other programming language.

Comment: thank you, yes, it's all one field, will look for options with coding then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using PHP, first you're better off with correcting those unrecognized booleans. You have `True` where it should have been `true` (*alternatively* `TRUE` for PHP) for it to evaluate the data right.

```
$jsStr = preg_replace_callback(
'~(?<=[,{[])(".+?"\s*:\s*)(true|false)(?=\s*[,}\]])~i',
create_function('$m','return $m[1].strtolower($m[2]);'),
$jsStr);
```

Then to be able to process it you want to use the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

```
$parsed = json_decode($jsStr);
// see the result if you like:
// print_r($parsed);
```

Ultimately if you want to extract some specific information on the client side (using Javascript) you can use the Array filter() function or a loop if you're not using jQuery. Otherwise you can use the [jQuery `filter()` function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with necessary conditions.

If you want to do this in PHP, after the string is parsed into JSON you can use the solutions that apply to Javascript.